# socketConnection error in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I am very new to `SparkR`. When I ran `sparkR`, something was wrong.

```
sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
```

error like this:

```
Error in socketConnection(port = monitorPort) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(port = monitorPort) : localhost:32811 cannot be opened
```

Somebody told me it's a localhost issue, but it didn't work when I change the localhost to local IP address. Is there really a problem in localhost setting?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following system variable: $EXISTING_SPARKR_BACKEND_PORT to an available port and rerun sparkR.